# Parsing empty lines delimited file - too slow

Tags: python

I'm have been struggling past couple of days trying to parse this text/pgm file used in chess game. You can assume this to be a .txt file. Every 2 blocks represents one game. The file looks something like:

```
[Event "15th Czerniak mem"]
[Site "Tel Aviv ISR"]
[Date "1999.04.05"]
[Round "6"]
[White "Karolyi, T"]
[Black "Lutz, C"]
[Result "0-1"]
[WhiteElo "2432"]
[BlackElo "2610"]
[ECO "A87"]

1.d4 f5 2.c4 Nf6 3.g3 g6 4.Bg2 Bg7 5.Nc3 O-O 6.Nf3 d6 7.d5 Qe8 8.Be3 Na6 
9.Qc1 e5 10.dxe6 Bxe6 11.O-O c6 12.b3 Ng4 13.Bf4 Qe7 14.Qd2 Rad8 15.Rad1 
Nc5 16.Nd4 Ne5 17.Bg5 Bf6 18.Bxf6 Qxf6 19.f4 Nf7 20.b4 Bxc4 21.Nxc6 bxc6 
22.bxc5 d5 23.Rfe1 d4 24.Na4 Rfe8 25.Rc1 Bd5 26.Bxd5 Rxd5 27.Nb2 Nh6 28.
Nd3 Ng4 29.Nf2 Ne3 30.Nd1 g5 31.Nxe3 Rxe3 32.Rf1 Qe6 33.Rf2 g4 34.Rb1 Rd7 
35.Qc2 Kg7 36.Rb3 Kf6 37.Rxe3 Qxe3 38.Qb2 Qc3 39.Qb8 Qxc5 40.Qc8 Qd5 41.
Rf1 Qe6 0-1

[Event "Danilo Batricevic Mem Balkan GP"]
[Site "Cetinje MNE"]
[Date "2012.10.24"]
[Round "6.6"]
[White "Nikcevic, N"]
[Black "Blagojevic, Dr"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
[WhiteElo "2432"]
[BlackElo "2526"]
[ECO "A14"]
[EventDate "2012.10.20"]
[WhiteTitle "GM"]
[BlackTitle "GM"]
[Opening "English opening"]
[Variation "Agincourt variation"]
[WhiteFideId "901776"]
[BlackFideId "900885"]

1.c4 e6 2.Nf3 d5 3.b3 Nf6 4.g3 Be7 5.Bg2 c5 6.O-O Nc6 7.e3 O-O 8.Bb2 b6 9.
Nc3 dxc4 10.bxc4 Bb7 11.Qe2 Rc8 12.Rac1 Qc7 13.d4 Na5 14.Nb5 Qb8 15.dxc5 
Bxc5 16.Bxf6 gxf6 17.Rfd1 Rfd8 18.Nh4 Bxg2 19.Nxg2 Nc6 20.Qg4+ Kh8 21.
Rxd8+ Nxd8 22.Qh4 Be7 23.Rd1 Nc6 24.Qh5 Kg8 25.Qg4+ Kh8 26.Qh5 Kg8 27.Qg4+
Kh8 1/2-1/2

[Event "FSGM October"]
[Site "Budapest HUN"]
[Date "2003.10.09"]
[Round "6"]
[White "Anka, E"]
[Black "Taylor, T"]
[Result "1-0"]
[WhiteElo "2432"]
[BlackElo "2385"]
[ECO "C41"]

1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 exd4 4.Nxd4 g6 5.Nc3 Bg7 6.Be3 Nf6 7.Qd2 O-O 8.O-O-O
Re8 9.f3 Nc6 10.g4 Ne5 11.Be2 a6 12.Bh6 Bh8 13.h4 b5 14.h5 b4 15.Nd5 c5 
16.Nf5 Nxd5 17.Qxd5 Be6 18.Qxd6 Qf6 19.g5 Nd3+ 20.Kd2 Qd8 21.hxg6 fxg6 22.
Bxd3 gxf5 23.Qxd8 Raxd8 24.Kc1 c4 25.exf5 cxd3 26.fxe6 Rxe6 27.Rd2 Rc6 28.
Kb1 Rcd6 29.Rxd3 Rxd3 30.cxd3 Rxd3 31.Rc1 Kf7 32.Rc8 Bd4 33.Kc2 1-0
.......
.......
```

Above you see a total of 3 games(== 6 sections) ! **Each game** is divided into 2 sections( one starting with `[Event "15th Czer...."` and other starting with those `1.d4 f5 2.f4...)` <-- **one game**. I'm trying to parse a very big file(~2 GB) similar to this. This is what I've tried but this is taking more than 10 minutues to even parse a simple file, extremely slow:

```
with open('data/chessgames.pgn', 'r', encoding='latin-1') as f:
    file_in_memory = f.read() # ~ 2 gb file in memory
    items = file_in_memory.strip().split('\n\n') #split on empty new lines
    list_of_games = []

item = 0
while item < len(items):
    summary = items[item].split("\n")  # str -> [Event "FIDE Candidates"]\n [Site "London ENG"] \n [Date "some date"....
    moves = items[item + 1]  # [ 1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bb5 Nf6 4.d3 ...
    if summary[0][0] != "[":   # sometime if I come across ill informed data
        item += 1
        continue
    item += 2
    #print(item)
    parser(summary, moves, list_of_games)  # function to parse the data

insert_into_database(list_of_games)  # BATCH INSERT (not inserting one at a time) array of ALL parsed games to be inserted in a sqlite3 db where each row is one game. Happy to share this function if anyone wants to see
```

And the `parser` function which is taking the most time:

```
def parser(summary, moves, list_of_games):
    row = {'Event': None, 'Site': None, 'Date': None, 'Round': None,
           'White': None, 'Black': None, 'Result': None,
           'WhiteElo': None, 'BlackElo': None,
           'ECO': None, 'EventDate': None, 'Opening': None,
           'Variation': None}

    for item in summary: # list -> [[Event "FIDE Candidates"], [Site "London ENG"],['Date....
        try:
            key, val = shlex.split(item[1:-1].strip())  # exclude the first and last brackets
            row[key] = val  # exclude the first and last double quotes
        except Exception as e:
            print("ERRORSS")
            logger.error("Exception raised: error parsing", e)

    chess = ChessSchema(row, moves)  # create an object of ChessSchema
    list_of_games.append(chess.ret_tuple_of_game())
```

How can I make this code the 'right' way, as this is taking way tooo long for even a medium size file. How can I make it fast? I tried generators, but even if I am keeping the whole file in memory, it should the fastest, as I assume. 
Lastly, here's what my ChessSchema class looks like:

```
class ChessSchema:
    """
    :param: parses 14 fields
    """
    def __init__(self, game_dict, moves):

        self.Event = game_dict['Event']
        self.Site = game_dict['Site']
        self.Date = game_dict['Date']
        self.White = game_dict['White']  # name
        self.Black = game_dict['Black']  # name
        self.Round = game_dict['Round']
        self.Result = game_dict['Result']
        self.ECO = game_dict['ECO']
        self.EventDate = game_dict['EventDate']
        self.Opening = game_dict['Opening']
        self.Variation = game_dict['Variation']
        self.moves = moves
        try:
            self.WhiteElo = int(game_dict['WhiteElo']) # white score
            self.BlackElo = int(game_dict['BlackElo'])  # black score
        except TypeError:
            self.WhiteElo = game_dict['WhiteElo']  # white score
            self.BlackElo = game_dict['BlackElo']  # black score
        self.winner = self.winner()

    def winner(self):
        if self.Result:
            if self.Result == "0-1":
                return "Black"
            elif self.Result == "1-0":
                return "White"
            else:
                return "Draw"

    def ret_tuple_of_game(self):
        return (self.Event, self.Site, self.Date, self.White, self.Black,
                self.Result, self.WhiteElo, self.BlackElo, self.ECO, self.EventDate,
                self.Opening, self.Variation, self.moves, self.winner)
```

UPDATE: I understand there's a pgn library for this, as someone mentioned in the comment, but I am trying to parse this as simple text file without using external libs(Or atleast give it a try!)
So based on the feedback in the comments regarding reading the file line by line and not dump entire file in memory, I tried this but failed, since there's only way to validate a section is by looking at the first character. If it's a "1" then its good, but if its not, then I don't want to count the following lines. Is the following better or faster than above in any way?

```
line = f.readline()
    while line: # reach till EOF

        print("LINE:" , line)
        #######################################################################
        # parse game headers [Event "Fide inv"]\n [Site "Fullerham"]....
            # print("game headers")

        if line.startswith("["):
            # print("LINES: ", line)
            while line.startswith("["):
                print(line)
                key, val = shlex.split(line[1:-2].rstrip())
                row[key] = val
                line = f.readline()

            # print(key, val)

            # else:
            #    break  # break out of the summary brackets

        if line.isspace():  # or if it starts with % or "\n"
            line = f.readline()
            all_games.append(row)
            # del all_games[:]
            # continue

        # print(line)
        analyze_data()

        #######################################################################
        # Parse moves info - move text
        if line.startswith("1"):
            tmp = ""
            while line and not line.isspace():
                line = f.readline()
                tmp += line
            row['moves'] = tmp

        line = f.readline()
```

Comment: there is a library for that: https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pgn.html

Comment: `file_in_memory = f.read()` Don't do that. Read the file line by line : read the header until you find an empty line. Read the moves until you find an empty line. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: `row = collections.defaultdict()`. This line is ignored by the following one.

Comment: Also, if your class is nothing more than a `dict`, you could use a `dict` and a function instead. How much RAM do you have? If you have 2GB file in memory, a huge list with at least 2GB worth of data and a 2GB sql query, it might explain why the process is so slow. You might want to process batches of 1000 games and put them one after the other in the DB.

Comment: Finally, what does `insert_into_database(list_of_games)` look like? If you have a list of thousands of games and insert them one by one in the DB, the process will be very slow.

Comment: @EricDuminil thanks for the suggestions. So I thought about reading line by line vs reading the whole file into memory. I'm fine with that since I've more than ~12 GB RAM. I chose to do the latter so better performance and easiness to split the data on "new lines". `Parser` function is being called for every data point, while `insert_into_database(list_of_games)` is called after parsing and "batch inserting" into a sqlite database, hence I have to enforce schema, but the `'parser` is just too slow even after keeping the file in memory :(

Comment: Trading memory for CPU might sometimes be a good idea. But with your script, you probably even use more than 12GB. My advice would be to read the file line by line, disable the DB import at first and parse the file without `shlex.split`. You could also do without `ChessSchema` class, though I don't think it has a big performance impact.

Comment: The problem I'm having in parsing line by line, because there are invalid lines within the file, which I don't have to count.. Because I can tell only by the starting character  in a 'section' that the following lines will be invalid. I tried but failed.. I've the updated my question with the approach..

Comment: Anyway I 've added the "line by line" approach. Do you think that's faster or better in any way? What you think?